obtener todos los datos de la entidad que da su id a otra tabla en entity framework
estoy construyendo una api rest en entity framework y tengo una entidad llamada estudiantes y luego otra entidad que se llama facultad, estudiantes hereda la llave foranea de facultad hasta ahi todo bien, ya las 2 tablas tienen sus controladores, pero cuando hago un get a la api de estudiantes solamente puedo ver el id que le puse que hereda de la tabla facultad mas no puedo ver los datos de la facultad, ahi alguna manera de ver todos los campos de facultad con la api de estudiantes

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! si, y depende de tu codigo.. muestra la implementacion de la clase estudiante...

Presiona [edit] y agrega ambas clases a tu pregunta.

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
